# In Visual Studio, for Console.WriteLine, type cw then TAB twice? or once?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In my computer, I type cw, then TAB twice, output Console.WriteLine.
Only TAB one time doesnot work.

But someones said they only TAB once, how do they do it?

Comment: I only have to press it once, but I have Resharper installed. Perhaps that's it?

Comment: I have suspended Re-Sharper but still it works with just a single TAB on Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Single long-press works without any extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trigger to complete a Visual Studio snippet, by default is two tab keypresses.

Perhaps the other person has an extension or add-in that changes the snippet behaviour.

Comment: but why someone told me that they do it by only pressing tab once?